# Read std::string line (with spaces and special keys support)

Tags: c++, string, std

I need read one line into `std::string str` from keyboard using console.
Now I use `std::getline(std::cin, str);` function.

But this method works wrong with arrow keys and other special keys (exept Backspace and Enter).

I hope that c++ already have pretty solution for this (but I can't google it), isn't it?

If this solution support "command history" (up/down arrow keys for prev/next command) it would be perfect.

I use ubuntu 12.10 if it important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll want to use the readline library (http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html), which has a lot of useful functionality, including history support.

Comment: Here's a simple example to get you started: http://web.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/C_cool_utils.html#readline

Comment: thank you! Nice library. Now I think that`std::string` is soap bubble. Because linereading is one of basic functionality of string (in my opinion) =(